# Why does using "position: fixed" cause the div below not to clear in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to break my content in bootstrap into a header/body such that only the body will be scrolled when necessary. But by using the position: fixed style the body div no longer clears the header div. So with the html below:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="header" style="position: fixed">
    <p> This is a header </p>
  </div>
  <div id="body" style="clear: both">
    <p> This is the body </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My body overlaps the header. How can I make it clear it? I am using bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: `clear` is meant to be used with `float`, not `position`. The only way is to add `margin-top` to `body`

Comment: So if I want to have a header sized dynamically depending on its content there is no way of using css to achieve a scrolling body?

Comment: JavaScript then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this layout you can use flexbox...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Aysgka8Yck

```
#content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%; 
    flex-direction: column;
}

#body {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```